# Laravel: Access denied for user homestead at localhost

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I just started a new Laravel project and I am having some database connectivity problem. First of all, I have only the User model which comes with the package. It has a migration as well. I updated my env file for the database path like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_project1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

The problem is, when I ran migrate command

```
php artisan migrate
```

It created those migrations in my database. But now when I am simply trying to do User::all(); I am having some trouble with this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

I have even cleared my config cache with this command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

EDIT:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'laravel_project1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

This seems to solve the problem but I don't understand why env file is not working as it is the recommended way I believe.

Comment: try looking at your database.php file in the config folder

Comment: If I put my credentials in database file, it works.

Comment: Did you restart the web server after running `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: @James nope, I didn't

Comment: are you still having trouble?

Comment: are you running artisan serve ?
try restarting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, as Vasil Gerginski said in comments below my question. Restarting solved the problem.

**When artisan starts, it caches your config. So even if you change it, it won't take affect until you restart artisan server.**

Answer (score 0):

The way Laravel's database config works is reading the **/config/database.php** file, so if you wan't Laravel to read your configuration from your .env file, you just have to make some changes in the **/config/database.php** for example:

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel_project1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

So now the **/config/database.php** file will read your .env file and if it fails to read it will have the default config (Which is the second argument of each env() function above...)